# how to set up a deny rule (e.g. Apache) to block a IP if it connects more than e.g. 5 times per second?

Tags: apache-http-server, firewall, htaccess

if I want to block any IPs that connects the server more than 5 times per second, how to do that?

I am currently using CloudFlare firewall to manually block such IPs but it would be nice to make it automatically in Apache2 server.

I know there is a .htaccess but not sure if this can be set to block such IPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step will be to [restore the correct user IP in your log files](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170786) so they show your user's IP Address instead of CloudFlare.

In order to do this you can install [Mod_CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads/).

After you've done this; you can then install Fail2Ban. [Fail2Ban can then be configured to Rate Limit](http://r3dux.org/2013/06/how-to-stop-apache-dos-attacks-with-fail2ban/) requests from IP Addresses of your choice.

Fail2Ban will then watch your Apache log file, once it spots excessive requests; those IPs will be banned using a firewall tool (e.g. IPTables). The Digital Ocean community has a great tutorial on [protecting Apache with Fail2Ban](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-an-apache-server-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04).